# Download video which is full screen of my browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, video

I guess this is a bit tricky, but I have the video in the following url:

```
url = "https://archive.org/embed/KTVU_20221120_180000_FOX_News_Sunday?start=1620&amp;end=1680"
```

How could I download it using Python?

Cheers!

Comment: So you haven't found it necessary to accept any of the answers you have gotten so far to the different questions you have previously posed. Why would anyone want to provide you with a solution if you don't even bother to mark it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't receive any answer yet. I don't get what are you talking about neither why this rude message.

Comment: You have asked 8 questions so far including this one.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a place to ask questions. If you have a nice answer, please share it, it would be very useful for me and for sure I'll mark it as an answer if it helps. Furthermore, the answers that I received of the last 3 questions that I did were voted positively by me so please, calm down dude.

Comment: Try this [URL](https://ia801404.us.archive.org/7/items/KTVU_20221120_180000_FOX_News_Sunday/KTVU_20221120_180000_FOX_News_Sunday.mp4?exact=1&start=1620&end=1740) to download the video you are after.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you can see, I gave it a +1, which is all what I can give now I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250119/discussion-between-mateo-and-sim).